# "database x is beign recovered" inside an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am pulling a report in ASP.NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2005. After running the report sometimes (not all the times), I get this message that database XXX is being recovered, please wait ...

My question is I do not even use that database in my application. My report is pulling data from another database. What does this message really mean? Do I need to worry about it.

I got it on development environment a couple of times before but now I got it on production environment as well.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, an extremely localized question, rather specific to your environment. Usually a database who gives that message is, indeed, in recovery mode after a crash. Why an unrelated database would report it is a bit of a mystery. Are you sure it's not related?

Comment: Look for linked servers. It's not going to throw an error for no reason.

Comment: The server is the same, but the database is different. I have two databases that the application uses. I am using A in my report, crash occurs in B.

Comment: Cross database query sounds likely. Or a user whose default database is the one being recovered.

Comment: @MattWhitfield no way. This applications is existence for many years. I recently wrote a new report and I saw this error never seen it before. Also this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249%28SQL.105%29.aspx) could be useful but I can't fully get it